# Spot creation failure (Using ASG with Instance Launch Template)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling, amazon-ec2-spot-market

/* My Configuration */

- EC2 Console limit : All Standard (A, C, D, H, I, M, R, T, Z) Spot Instance Requests 128vCPU
- Region : ap-northeast-2
- Current Instance count : 0

Currently, I've no instances running on AWS (all spot instance terminated).
And I using ASG(Auto Scaling Group) with Instance Launch Template (No spot option).
When I try to launch a new instance with Instance Launch Template, it's OK. (instance type : c5.large)

But when I try to launch a new spot instance with Instance Launch Template (Check spot option),
it tells me that "Max spot instance count exceeded".

## ASG Activity)

Status : Failed
Description : Launching a new EC2 instance. Status Reason: Max spot instance count exceeded. Launching EC2 instance failed.

Help me please...

Comment: Is your AWS Account relatively new (eg only a few days)?

Comment: Check the outstanding Spot requests/Fleets/ASGs in your account. If you terminate your Spot Instances but do not cancel the Spot Instance requests, the requests count against your Spot Instance vCPU limit until Amazon EC2 detects the Spot Instance terminations and closes the requests. according to the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-limits.html#monitoring-spot-limits

Comment: Hi.  I did cancel all spot requests.

Comment: I resolved..   I found my problem in AWS document. --> " "Check the outstanding Spot requests/Fleets/ASGs in your account".  Thank you so much John.